# How to attach different value for additional field in pivot table Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have `project_group` pivot table with this fields: `id, group_id, project_id, admin_id, user_id`

This I use to attach group and projects together:

```
$group -> projects() -> attach($projects,array('admin_id' => Auth::user()->id));
```

Is it possible to for every record in that pivot table add diffirent user_id.

For example:

First record:

`id` = 1,  `group_id` = 1 `project_id` = 2 `admin_id` = 1 `user_id` = 1

Second record:

`id` = 2,  `group_id` = 1 `project_id` = 3 `admin_id` = 1 `user_id` = 1

3th record:

`id` = 3,  `group_id` = 1 `project_id` = 2 `admin_id` = 1 `user_id` = 2

4th record:

`id` = 3,  `group_id` = 1 `project_id` = 3 `admin_id` = 1 `user_id` = 2

Basicly if I select 2 projects from projects html list and 2 users from html users list I need to get result like in example above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution, if someone has better way please put here...

```
$projectsIds = [11,33];

        $userIds = [1,2,4];
        $adminId = Auth::id();

        if($group -> save()){
        foreach($userIds as $userId){
           $group -> projects() -> attach($projectsIds,array('admin_id' => $adminId, 'user_id' => $userId));

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, like this:

```
$projects = [
    2 => ['admin_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 1],
    3 => ['admin_id' => 1, 'user_id' => 2],
    // and so on
];
$group->projects()->attach($projects);
```

And if I understood your problem right, you can build such an array like this:

```
$projectsIds = [2,3];
$userIds = [1,2];
$projects = [];
$adminId = Auth::id();
foreach($userIds as $userId){
    $projects += array_fill_keys($projectIds, [
        'admin_id' => $adminId,
        'user_id' => $userId
    ]);
}
$group->projects()->attach($projects);
```

Comment: I need to keep `project_id`, so I should get `diffrent user_id for diffirent project_id`.... When I select 2 projects from projects html list and 2 users from html users list I need to get result like in example above...

Comment: It will return like array like this: `array:4 [  0 => array:2 [    "admin_id" => 1    "user_id" => 1  ]  1 => array:2 [    "admin_id" => 1    "user_id" => 1  ]  2 => array:2 [    "admin_id" => 1    "user_id" => 2  ]  3 => array:2 [    "admin_id" => 1    "user_id" => 2  ]]` projects will be ignored, but I need also projects to be attached... :)

Comment: Ah ye right, `array_merge` reindexes the array. Try to just add (`+`) them, like in my updated answer...

Comment: It return unsuported operator, anyway thanks for try to help I found soulutin below... And I will give you vote up cose you give me idea...